# HDD detects in bios but not booting

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, desktop-computer

I have a Western 160GB HDD and a Samsung 16GB HDD mounted. My pc runs on the Samsung HDD at the moment. If I plug my Western HDD in while windows 7 is already running, everything is fine. If I plug the Western HDD in before booting the computer, it gets detected by the BIOS with the status set at `Ok` but it doesn't boot at all.

With other words:

Why doesn't the computer boot when I have my second HDD plugged in?

Comment: Internal hard disks **are not hot-pluggable**. By plugging in a hard disk while the PC is powered on, you're risking damaging either the disk or the computer.

Comment: SATA disks are absolutely [hot swappable with an AHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) controller.

Comment: Sorry for bad english

Comment: I get the answer just making new partion solved the problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bios bug or more likely it's trying to boot your second disk before your Windows OS disk. Try disabling boot from that device in the BIOS.

If that doesn't work and the disk is empty (seriously, this will destroy your data), try zeroing the partition table (and the rest of the drive) with diskpart's `clean all` subcommand.

[Microsoft documentation on diskpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766465(v=ws.10))